# Свой класс меню для приложения Java

Tags: java, swing

Я создал класс на основе класса `JMenu`, который принимает строковый `ArrayList`, хранящий названия подпунктов меню, и строку с названием пункта меню.

Например, пункт меню `"файл"` и его подпункты `"новый", "сохранить", "сохранить как"` и т.д.

Вот конструктор моего класса

```
package TextEditor;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TextEditorMenuItem extends JMenu {

 private ArrayList<JMenuItem> menu_items;
 private String menuName;
 private JMenu menuItem;
TextEditorMenuItem(String menu_name, ArrayList<String> menu_item_names) {
    menuName =menu_name;
    for (int i = 0; i < menu_item_names.size() - 1; i++) {
        JMenuItem menu = new JMenuItem(menu_item_names.get(i));
        menu_items.add(menu);
    }
}
public JMenu getItems (){
    for(int i = 0; i<menu_items.size()-1;i++) {
        menuItem = new JMenu(menuName);
        menuItem.add(menu_items.get(i));

     };
    return menuItem;
    };
}
```

Вот класс главного окна

```
package TextEditor;
import javax.swing.*;
import TextEditor.TextEditorMenu;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


 public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
 private ArrayList<String> menus;
 private ArrayList<String> menu_item;
 private TextEditorMenu menu_item_str;
 MainWindow(){
    setTitle("Текстовый редактор");
    menus = new ArrayList<String>();
    menus.add ("Файл");
    menus.add ("Правка");
    menus.add("Формат");
    menus.add("Справка");

    menu_item = new ArrayList<String>();
    menu_item.add("Новый");
    menu_item.add("Открыть");
    menu_item.add("Сохранить");
    menu_item.add("Сохранить как...");
    menu_item.add("Печать");
    menu_item.add("Выход");
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.add(new TextEditorMenuItem(menus.get(0), menu_item).getItems());
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.setSize(500,500);
    mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainWindow.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Ошибок синтаксиса нет, но при компиляции, возникают следующие исключения:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   TextEditor.TextEditorMenuItem.(TextEditorMenuItem.java:15)  at
>   TextEditor.MainWindow.(MainWindow.java:29)  at
>   TextEditor.MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:35)

Где я ошибся? помогите исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.JMenu;

public class TextEditorMenuItem extends JMenu {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3879042423861560439L;

    private final JMenu menuItem;

    public TextEditorMenuItem(String menuName, String ... menuItemNames) {
        this.menuItem = new JMenu(menuName);
        for (String mi : menuItemNames) menuItem.add(mi);
    }

    public JMenu getItems() {
        return menuItem;
    }

}

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3927651758148511702L;    
    private final static String[] MENU = {"Файл", "Правка", "Формат", "Справка"};
    private final static String[] MENU_ITEM = {"Новый", "Открыть", "Сохранить",
        "Сохранить как...", "Печать", "Выход"};

    public MainWindow create(String [] menu, String [] menuItem) {
        setTitle("Текстовый редактор");
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        for (String m : menu) menuBar.add(new TextEditorMenuItem(m, menuItem).getItems());        
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow().create(MENU, MENU_ITEM);
    }

}
```

У меня не хватает для компиляции переменной - private TextEditorMenu menu_item_str, посему я ее убрал. Без нее все работает. Обратите внимание на правила именования переменных. Кроме того, цикл такого вида `for(int i = 0; i<menu_items.size()-1;i++)`  работает некорректно. Он не читает последний элемент итерируемой коллекции (а если его читать не нужно, то зачем его создавать). А еще не ленитесь делать рефакторинг. Среда разработки сама подсказывает многие проблемные места кода. Не игнорируйте эти подсказки. Избыточность кода - это всегда плохо. Удачи)

Comment: а как добавить следующий пункт меню?

Comment: код изменил, теперь пунктов меню несколько...